# How to edit stored data in MongoDB using Express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, crud

How to do update a document in MongoDB with express as a backend?

Here is the Backend API

```
app.post("/update",(req,res)=>{
      
    const id=req.body.id;
    console.log(id);
    contact.updateOne({'_id':id},req.body,(err,res)=>{
        if(err) throw err

        console.log('data edited....')

    });

    res.redirect("/show");
    console.log("done..");
});
```

Comment: what do you want to acheive?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for updating a document

```
app.patch("/update", (req, res) => {
    const id = req.body.id;
    console.log(id);
    contact.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, (err, res) => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log('data edited....')
    });
    res.redirect("/show");
    console.log("done..");
});
```

Hope this will help you...